# Ubuntu One suddenly fails to sync

Tags: ubuntu-one

U1 file sync between computers (laptops, desktop, running 12.04) after years of uninterrupted service *suddenly* fails (since at least a day, yesterday I noticed it for the first time). Last successful download sync was 21 Feb 10:00 CET.

Uploading directly using the Web interface does not work either; after 3 tries it fails with "No files were uploaded due to an error." (even with a tiny text file "u1test.txt" with just "test" in it). As long direct upload to U1 does not work, there is something seriously wrong with sync.

An "answer" giving in a separate post (install ubuntuone-couch is not relevant as it is already installed). Nor delete file names with spaces...

I rely on U1 as my daily cloud service of choice for quite some time now.

Comment: Using another browser and deleting a file with the Web interface (and no devices linked) fails also. Something might be wrong at the U1 side... (this is similar to [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/424676/no-write-permission-on-ubuntu-one-web-client)

Comment: And "stop publishing" does not work either.

Comment: Tried it with Android 4.2 (Ubuntu One App): When opening the app the error message apeared: "Error: Could not get node. No resources found". Tried it on Ubuntu 12.04 (U1 Client). Status says: Not Connected. If i hit "connect" it takes a while, but with no access. Status remains at "not connected. I can connect via the web-interface. But i did not try to upload or download any file.

Comment: This is server issues. There have been DDoSes going around.

Answer (score 3):

This is a server issue.

See the number of issues just raised in the past few days, several of which have comments indicating experienced users believe it to be a server issue:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/425271/ubuntuone-remains-paused
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/425228/ubuntu-one-unable-to-sync-even-a-text-file
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/425173/ubuntu-one-not-syncing-in-lubuntu-nor-bohi
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/425271/ubuntuone-remains-paused
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/424109/ubuntu-one-no-more-syncing

Update: [Asked on Twitter for an announcement](https://twitter.com/mlncn/status/437707665297256448) if there's a problem.  There's a notice on their status wiki page — https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status — but not clearly related to this.  (Also, i tried Nocturnalknight's solution and deleting and the device and reconnecting, and the signing in works but the sync doesn't.)

Comment: And indeed everything started working, without changes on my side one day after posting this, and has been working fine since.  Canonical's lack of response or update to the status wiki is disappointing though.

Answer (score -1):

What Version kernel u have? 
I too had the same issue form 22/02/2014 ..I tried unlinking and relinking the device (my Laptop) and it works again. After disconnecting from U1, plz reboot before re-connecting and be sure to delete the settings and cache after removing U1

```
$ sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
$ rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
```

Also PLz remove/rename the old Ubuntu One folder and retry with just a small txt file(as described by you)
Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Current Kernel is:
    
"3.8.0-36-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:54:46 UTC 2014"    .    

Removed U1, removed caches, and signed in again. During sign in process the panel on "Syncing the cloud to your computer/These are the folders in your cloud. Select the ones you want to sync with this computer." says "Getting information, please wait"... takes ages (ie. does not finish).
         
Uploading to the Web still fails (shouldn't be related to the kernel); a tiny file upload 100% three times then fails with: "No files were uploaded due to an error."

Comment: disconnected all devices in the web interface, the laptop disconnected/signed out from U1... uploading to the web/U1 cloud directly still fails.